# fabric.js canvas to json with svg custom attributes

Tags: fabricjs

I added new attributes for path svg:

```
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
   var group = [];


fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svg_file, function(objects,options) {
            var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            obj.set({
                left: 100,
                top: 100
            });
            canvas.add(obj);
            canvas.renderAll();

        },
        // add new attributes
        function(item, object) {
            object.set('id',item.getAttribute('id'));
            object.set('tag_id', tag_id);
            object.set('elem_id', elem_id );
            group.push(object);
        }
);
```

And:

```
// see new attributes
console.log(canvas.getObjects());
// save to JSON
console.log('json:', canvas.toJSON())
```

But new attributes not save.
[Saving JSON in canvas with fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763057/saving-json-in-canvas-with-fabric-js) not work for me.

I read [Saving JSON in canvas with fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763057/saving-json-in-canvas-with-fabric-js),
it says to create a new class based on fabric.Image, it works for me,
but what to do with fabric.LoadSVGFromURL and fabric.util.groupSVGElements?
Need to create a new class or something else? Help me.

**Solved:**

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/471

http://jsfiddle.net/Ypn2k/4/

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set custom attribute in this way :

```
svgelement.toObject = (function (toObject) {
                            return function () {
                                return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                                    "custom_attr_key": "Value",
                                    "custom_attr_key": "Value",
                                });
                            };
                        })(svgelement.toObject);
```

and also pass this custom attribute key in toJson function like This :

```
canvas.toJSON(['custom_attr_key','custom_attr_key']);
```